# Supabase auth not storing anything in cookies sveltekit

Tags: authentication, sveltekit, supabase

I am trying to build a simple supabase application, I have followed the documentation for the "auth" section exactly, as far as I can tell. Currently, I am generating a magic link, getting a hash token, verifying that token, and then forwarding them to "/admin". Every step of this is working perfectly.

However, when they are forwarded to the admin landing page, it checks for a current user session. This check always comes up null, and in the browser cookies section I only have a -auth-token-code-verifier, not a session/refresh token. How is this possible? Why aren't tokens being stored when verifyOtp is called?

Very strangely, this is all working when I run the webpage locally and set the site URL to localhost:5713 in the config section of supabase auth.

this is my hooks.server.ts file, as you can see, it is exactly the same as from the website. The cookies aren't being stored, and so I assume the error might be here. I have tried changing the path. Setting it to '/admin' works on localhost, but nothing works when running in deployment.

```
import { PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY } from '$env/static/public'
import { createServerClient } from '@supabase/ssr'
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  event.locals.supabase = createServerClient(PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY, {
    cookies: {
      get: (key) => event.cookies.get(key),
      /**
       * Note: You have to add the `path` variable to the
       * set and remove method due to sveltekit's cookie API
       * requiring this to be set, setting the path to an empty string
       * will replicate previous/standard behaviour (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-cookies)
       */
      set: (key, value, options) => {
        event.cookies.set(key, value, { ...options, path: '' })
      },
      remove: (key, options) => {
        event.cookies.delete(key, { ...options, path: '' })
      },
    },
  })

  /**
   * a little helper that is written for convenience so that instead
   * of calling `const { data: { session } } = await supabase.auth.getSession()`
   * you just call this `await getSession()`
   */
  event.locals.getSession = async () => {
    const {
      data: { session },
    } = await event.locals.supabase.auth.getSession()
    return session
  }

  return resolve(event, {
    filterSerializedResponseHeaders(name) {
      return name === 'content-range'
    },
  })
}
```

this is in routes/admin/+page.server.ts

```
const {
        url,
        locals: { getSession }
    } = event;

    if (await getSession() == null) {
        throw redirect(302, '/admin/login');
    }
```

I have also tried calling setSession directly from the session returned from verifyOtp, something that is not in the docs, with the same results. All of my code is character-for-character identical to the sveltekit section of the supabase auth docs, my email configs have tokens, etc. Supabase logs show a sucessfull login event, and then less than a second later, a 500 error that the user has not been found.

I am at a loss as for what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in the same position as you. I've been trying it out for a couple of hours already and couldn't get it to work as well.

I tried to look into Supabase's open issues and it seems like this is an ongoing issue with the new SSR package. Someone there suggested a workaround but I haven't tried it yet.

You can check it our here: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/20141

**Update:** I just tried out the suggested workaround, it didn't work for me. I'll probably try going back to use the auth-helpers.

**Update #2:** I was able to get it to work with the ssr package by combining some workarounds for the auth-helpers package.

I had to add `+layout.svelte` that was defined in the auth-helpers documentation. It's this:

```
<!-- src/routes/+layout.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation'
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  export let data

  let { supabase, session } = data
  $: ({ supabase, session } = data)

  onMount(() => {
    const {
      data: { subscription },
    } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, _session) => {
      if (_session?.expires_at !== session?.expires_at) {
        invalidate('supabase:auth')
      }
    })

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  });
</script>

<slot />
```

With that, you would get a cookie error after signing in. I added a workaround that was suggested in this thread: https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/issues/466.

So my `hooks.server.ts` file now looks like this:

```
import { PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY } from '$env/static/public';
import { createServerClient } from '@supabase/ssr';
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    event.locals.supabase = createServerClient(PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, {
        cookies: {
            get: (key) => event.cookies.get(key),
            /**
             * Note: You have to add the `path` variable to the
             * set and remove method due to sveltekit's cookie API
             * requiring this to be set, setting the path to an empty string
             * will replicate previous/standard behaviour (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-cookies)
             */
            set: (key, value, options) => {
                event.cookies.set(key, value, { ...options, path: '/' });
            },
            remove: (key, options) => {
                event.cookies.delete(key, { ...options, path: '/' });
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * a little helper that is written for convenience so that instead
     * of calling `const { data: { session } } = await supabase.auth.getSession()`
     * you just call this `await getSession()`
     */
    let sessionRetrieved = false;
    event.locals.getSession = async () => {
        sessionRetrieved = true;
        const {
            data: { session }
        } = await event.locals.supabase.auth.getSession();
        return session;
    };

    if (!sessionRetrieved) {
        await event.locals.supabase.auth.getSession();
    }

    return resolve(event, {
        filterSerializedResponseHeaders(name) {
            return name === 'content-range';
        }
    });
};
```

It worked for me after that. Let me know if that fixes your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared works. However, I encountered an issue when I made `logout` its route, allowing users to log out by navigating to `/app/logout`. I placed the logout link in my protected route(/app), and Svelte was prefetching this page. As a result, it was logging me out whenever I reloaded the page, even without clicking anything. If you have a similar setup, make sure to change `data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover"` to `data-sveltekit-preload-data="off"` in your `app.html` to turn off preload.